# How to provide Issue fixes, release update of eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

How to provide Issue fixes, release update of eclipse RCP application, My Application having 200+ plugin and product is configured as a plugin not the feature. 
I am newbie for RCP p2 update so having couple of questions.

1. Can I use equinox p2 update feature to provide update for plug-in, because most of all blogs given example with feature only and my product configured as plug-in.
2. Is there any way to update plugin version automatically, let say I have fixed some bugs due to which 2-3 plug-in are modified so need to change the version of this plug-in manually
3. And also need to update other plug-in which depend of this updated plug-in. So should i provide 
   version range in dependencies?
4. Which plug-in pick-up if two version are present, let say I have plug-in my-console.1.0.0.jar and  then i have fixed some issue and updated the version to my-console.1.0.1.jar, now if user take the update then which plug-in version will get picked ? Its depending upon latest version or with timestamp ?
5. What if I deleted some plug-in, how this is get deleted using p2 update.
6. Also need some good resource of how patch fix, release updated notification given to RCP application user, How p2 central repository created, Standard guideline of Issue fixes, release update through p2.

Comment: This is way too broad making it difficult for any one person to answer.

Comment: Yes, you should define your RCP application as a set of features instead as a set of plugins to be able to follow best practices and to use p2, Tycho, etc.